# Calculate arc length given integral

Tags: calculus

My homework (second semester Calc) asks me to compute arc lengths. The first few problems give me a function and a range, but the last few give me an integral and a range, such as this one:

[image]

Where do I begin here? How does my approach change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y'^2 = 4 \sin^2{x}-1$$

Take it from there.

Comment: Interesting. Can you help me understand why that works? Does this work if the body of the integral isn't under a radical? How do I know it's okay to plug x in for t? Because x is given as the upper bound of integration? Are we discarding the fact that the lower bound is 0, or is that incorporated here in a way that I'm missing?

Comment: It follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x f(t) \, dt = f(x)$$

Comment: ahh, funny how the most important things we learn can be the first to be forgotten...